# What are the proper rewrite rules to use for a polymer app

Tags: nginx, routes, polymer

I am developing a polymer app, and have it running fine locally using the "polymer serve" cli command.

If I enter a route, it is properly handled. If I enter an incorrect .html url e.g. localhost/test.html, I receive a 404, which is what I expect.

However when I deploy to a site using nginx, html files that do not exist are not returning 404s. Instead, I believe that the

try_files $uri /index.html

directive is sending everything back to index.html

What is the best practice to change this, so that my site properly handles 404s while still properly resolving routes?

Basically I want localhost/filedoesntexist.html to 404
and localhost/filedoesntexist to be directed to index.html

Is this the right way of thinking about the problem or am I missing some polymer feature?